# Complex kibana visualization - group part of a message and display it's count

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We are logging all our applications logs to ElasticSearch.
We are using kibana to view and search the logs and we have also built some dashboards to display different reports.
I am trying to build a report that shows how many log entries we have for each of our methods.
The methodname is part of the log message field.
for example: log message is "exiting method name = 'DoSomething1' which took 300ms"
can i filter all logs for "method name = " and group all method names values and display the count for each of them in kibana graph?
I hope my question is clear.
thanks,
Guy.